# Точная высота элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется блок с `overflow: hidden`, где часть контента скрыта за его границами. И есть кнопка "Развернуть блок". Нужно сделать так, чтобы эта кнопка удалялась при загрузке страницы, если все содержимое блока отображается на экране (в ней нет необходимости). Как можно проверить точную высоту блока вместе со всем содержимым? `scrollHeight` точного значения не дает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обернуть как вариант. Вот пример на скорую руку.

```js
$('.wrap').each(function(i, v) {
  if ($(v).find('.test').height() >= $(v).find('.test1').height()) {
    $(v).find('button').hide();
  }
})
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.test').animate({
    height: $(this).parent().find('.test1').height()
  });
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  float: left;
  background: #eee
}
.test {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative
}
.test1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">1</div>
  </div>
  <button>ok</button>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate deleniti delectus, sit iste sapiente, reprehenderit vero culpa repudiandae, assumenda sint sequi. Accusantium cumque commodi ab! Autem fugit voluptatum molestias modi.</div>
  </div>
  <button>ok</button>
</div>
```